# iframe scrollbars during resize of fancybox 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fancybox-2

I set up a fancybox to load a form as an iframe. Fancybox autosizes depending on the size of the iframe content. This works well. But if I send the form now and have errors the iframe content get higher so the fancybox has to resize which happens.

But during resize I see ugly scrollbars till the lightbox has resized to match the new content.

Is there any possbility to adjust fancybox without having scrollbars during that? Probably a css property `overflow: hidden;` at the right events right in time could do the trick?

My setup of fancybox is very basic

```
$(".popup").fancybox({
    type: 'iframe',
    padding: 0
});
```

Comment: If you downvote my question please at least leave feedback as a comment. Thx.

Comment: It is perfectly acceptable to answer your own question and accept that answer. You should move your soution section to an answer. I hate drive by down votes too!

Comment: @JonP Okay I moved my solution to a new answer and have to wait now for 2 days unit I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solutions is this:

I was reading trough the documentation of FancyBox 2 and I adjusted my settings to:

```
$(".popup").fancybox({
    type: 'iframe',
    padding: 0,
    iframe: {
        scrolling : 'no'
    }
});
```

This hides scrollbar. But the resize happens to late. It takes about 1 second after display of new content until fancybox resizes to the new content dimensions in the iframe.

If the site which is loaded in the iframe is owned by yourself. You can add the following jquery Code into the `<body>` of the page loaded in the fancybox iframe:

```
<script>
        (function() {
            parent.$('.fancybox-inner').height($('body').innerHeight());
            parent.$.fancybox.reposition();
        })();
</script>
```

Fancybox resizes now immediately after content is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your exact case but adding

```
function myFunc(){
    $(".fancybox-iframe").attr("scrolling", "no");
}
```

should remove the scrollbar from the iframe once and for all.

You can add this as a call back function for the fancybox.

```
'callBackOnShow': myFunc()
```

Comment: Thx for answer. But the iframe is inside and managed by the fancybox.

Comment: Did you try this? it shouldn't matter if the iframe is managed by fancybox, the jquery should take effect and remove the scrollbars.

Comment: The iframe is not inside the `.popup` element. The element is like: `<a href="location/to/load/in/iframe" class="popup">click</a>`

Comment: what happens when you click on the link? can you check your dom and see on which div does the iframe sit? you can use firebug in firefox or inspect element in chrome

Comment: Which version of fancybox are refering to? This seems to be version 1.x I user 2.1.5